# Ember.Select not working on new record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a 'user' model with a property `selectedGroups: hasMany('group')`.  When I am editing an existing user, I am able to use `Ember.Select` in the template like this:

```
{{view Ember.Select
  multiple="true"
  class="form-control"
  selectionBinding="selectedGroups"
  contentBinding="controllers.groups.allGroups"
  optionLabelPath="content.name"
  optionValuePath="content.id"}}
```

and my `save` action looks like this:

```
Usermanagement.UserEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['groups'],
    actions: {
        save: function() {
            var user = this.get('model');
            user.save();
            this.transitionToRoute('user', user);
        },
```

etc..  This works perfectly.  However, this technique does not work when creating a new user.  I have a `users/new` route, like this:

```
Usermanagement.UsersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {};
  }
});
```

In my template, I'm using an Ember.Select view, like this:

```
        {{view Ember.Select
            prompt="Please select group(s)"
            multiple="true"
            class="form-control"
            selectionBinding="newUsersGroups"
            contentBinding="controllers.groups.allGroups"
            optionLabelPath="content.name"
            optionValuePath="content.id"
            }}
```

In this case, I have learned that the model does not have the property, so the Select creates a property on the controller by that name `newUsersGroups`.  My controller:

```
Usermanagement.UsersNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['groups'],
    newUsersGroups: [],
    actions: {
        addNewUser: function() {
            var that = this;
            var newuser = this.get('model');
            var grps= this.get('newUsersGroups');
            newuser.selectedGroups= grps;
            var user = this.store.createRecord('user', newuser);
            // user.set('selectedGroups', grps);
            user.save().then(function() {
                that.transitionToRoute('users');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

If I inspect the 'grps' variable in the debugger, I get:

```
Ember.inspect(grps)
"[<Usermanagement.Group:ember558:1>]"
```

This corresponds to the correct ID (1) of the group I selected.  However, I can't seem to set the selected groups in the new record.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a hash of properties to `createRecord` is simply a shorthand for creating a record and then calling `setProperties` on that record. That means passing

```
{selectedGroups: [...]}
```

is identical to

```
user.set('selectedGroups', [...]}
```

Unfortunately, as written the `hasMany` function creates a computed property that does not act as a setter. To be clear: if you call `set` on a `hasMany` property, it will have no effect. The computed property does absolutely nothing with the value you pass in. You will have to add the records to the user after you have created it, by calling `pushObjects` on the `selectedGroups` attribute.

Comment: Wow.  Ok.  I've got it working by putting `user.get('selectedGroups').pushObjects(that.get('newUsersGroups'));` **after** I've done the save..  Weird, but it works!  Thanks for your answer!